# Video problems switching from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: drivers, video, system-installation

I use ubuntu 10.04 and I'm trying to switch to 12.04 **via clean install**

When I boot from the pendrive to install 12.04, the screen loses signal and turns to black.

I use a NVidia GT520 video card.

Is this because 12.04 needs a driver? How should I proceed to install correctly?.

I'm willing to put screenshots and everything if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

how are you trying to switch? Did you do this gradually upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10 to 11.04 to 11.10 to 12.04? or are you doing a clean install of 12.04? Because if you're trying to upgrade from 10.04 you have to do this gradually. How to [Upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes) correctly.

Comment: Clean install. Let me add to the question.

Comment: hmm I myself installed Ubuntu 12.04 on laptop and Home PC and lots of where using simple Manual [Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) not to miss anything, everything worked fine always. Check if you did everything right. I also have Nvidia.

Comment: I can also advice this guides on Nvidia Driver [HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual) all about Nvidia you can read there.

Comment: try this workout as provided in manual: 
 1. Switch to the console by using ctrl+alt+F1, or reboot and select recovery mode from the GRUB menu.

   2.Open and edit xorg.conf like this: sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

   3.Find the line that says: Section "Screen"

   4.Insert a new line that says Option "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP".

   5.Save the file. If you had to restart into recovery mode, type reboot, otherwise restart your display using sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart.